# AWS MSK: deploying all Kafka brokers in the same availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, kafka

When using [AWS MSK](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/), is it possible to deploy Kafka brokers in the same AWS availability zone?

From what I read, AWS enforces deployments across availability zones. If you use three brokers, it will require three subnets in different availability zones. Is that true or is there a way to bypass that restriction?

---

Background: for most situations, deploying across zones is a good idea, but we are operating a subsystem where availability is not crucial and where all services are running in the same availability zone. Traffic in the same AZ is free, so we would prefer that if possible. If Kafka is unavailable if the whole data center behind that AZ goes down, would be acceptable. Most likely, the whole subsystem would not work in that scenario anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot back it up with links to the documentation, but my strong assumption is that it is not possible. AWS MSK forces cross availability-zone deployments. (In most cases, it is a good idea, anyway. I understand that the scenario in my question is not so common.)

The only option to stay in the same availability zone is to use only one broker. However, it is not recommended to run Kafka with a single broker. Therefore it is not an attractive option.